# Keeping Footer At The Bottom Of The Page Without Scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, styles, footer

Below is the code that I'm using to create a footer on my website. It looks the way I'd like it to, but have to scroll down to see it on a page that doesn't have much content on it. I'd like it to be at the bottom of the screen without having to scroll down no matter what size the screen may be.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? How can I get the footer to stay at the bottom of any screen size without have to scroll down to see it?

```
<html>
<body>

<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">MORIKOBOSHI©</footer>

<style>
 .footer{display: block;
           width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: fixed;
           bottom: 0;
           left: 0;
          right: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
     
    .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 10px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
 }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why ios tag here.

Comment: Because I'm using an iPhone 12 to check how the website runs on a mobile device. I would like the footer to stay at the bottom of a page on a mobile device too.